# How to play audio from WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, socket.io

I've been looking for how to play audio from the WebView when using socket.io to make a sound notification with my web chat application.

I've noticed Chrome Browser playing the audio but my WebView app doesn't play it. Can you please provide me any resource or code snippet?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you referring to a JavaFX WebView?

Comment: nope. only java!